# Sudo hangs without prompting for password

Tags: sudo

I just did a fresh install of Ubuntu and now when I try to use sudo in the terminal emulator, it just hangs there without even asking me for a password.
If I switch to the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + F1) and login, sudo works as expected.
Can someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: Just a thought, have you changed the character encoding of your terminal (Open Terminal, menu Terminal -> Set Character Encoding)

Comment: No, I haven't, but I am curious as to why that would change anything.

Comment: It can be the source of many problems if you change something like this, actually. But this was just a guess.

Comment: I had the same problem. Changing from kernel 4.9 to 4.4 solved it for me.

Answer (score 24):

Have you changed the hostname recently? I've noticed after a hostname change sudo can hang for a bit. However, if you update your hosts file to reflect the hostname change the hang will go away.

You can do that with this simple one-liner:

```
hostname | (echo -n "127.0.0.1        " && cat) | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
```

Comment: It does not hang for 'a bit', it just hangs indefinitely. Also, it works on the terminal, just not in the terminal emulator.

Comment: Give this man a cookie! Thanks when changing the `Device Name` in Ubuntu's system details utility you effectively break sudo. Great work @Canonical.

Comment: to fix it make sure to change `/etc/hosts` also to your new hostname ;)

Comment: Great! I didn't actually notice that it timed out after ~30 sec and then continue with asking for sudo password. Another point: when you is about to change your hostname (maybe you cloned a VM) you might be disconnected to any network to avoid conflicts until you have change the entries. That's is properly also what's causing the timeouts

Answer (score 6):

If you want to check where it hangs, I suggest doing the executing the following command:

```
 strace sudo
```

and then see what system call it is possibly hanging on.  This might provide a good clue as to what is happening on your system.

My guess based on what you see is that hostname resolution is problematic on your system.  Check out /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/resolv.conf files to make sure they are configured properly.

I have assummed that you have already checked your internet connectivity.

Comment: Why is internet connectivity required for sudo?

Comment: for FQDN information...as you can put host restrictions in your sudoers file.

Comment: I did not understand that. I only know that it makes it tricky to reset the wifi adapter. Which is sometimes necessary after putting the laptop in sleep.

Comment: One issue with this approach is that `strace` won't be able to trace into a setuid binary unless it also is installed with the setuid bit set (which it is not by default on Ubuntu). See the `SETUID INSTALLATION` section of `man strace`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of ubuntu you have installed,  but there is a bug (race condition) in sudo, which hangs indefinitely blocking on a select.

https://bugzilla.sudo.ws/show_bug.cgi?id=447

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem with Ubuntu 16.04 . Using "top" command i found that two processes "vnstat" and "NetworkManager" are consuming 100% CPU. So i restarted the system,  went to recovery mode and removed the package "vnstat" . After this restarted the system , now system works fine.