# sudo hangs without (not prompting password)

Tags: sudo

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
Originally my problem was, that my WLAN didn't work anymore, so I was browsing through ask-ubuntu to find a solution just to realize that sudo hangs without prompting my password. I came across [Sudo hangs without prompting for password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326194/sudo-hangs-without-prompting-for-password) but being an unexperienced Linux user my problem is that I don't even understand e.g. the output of strace :-) and the answers did not bring me any further.

`strace sudo` ends with:

```
[...]
write(2, "effective uid is not 0, is /usr/"..., 133effective uid is not 0, is /usr/bin/sudo on a file system with the 'nosuid' option set or an NFS file system without root privileges?) = 133
write(2, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

I did not change anything like the hostname (at least on purpose) and sudo worked fine until now. The only thing that might come to my mind is that I accidentially killed something important by using the `killall +PID` command. Sorry if I can't make my problem more clear.

Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance.

Stete

Comment: The permissions on the `sudo` binary may have been modified by some other debugging you've done in the past. What's the output of `ls -l $(which sudo)` ? For me it's `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 182472 Jul  8 17:38 /usr/bin/sudo` (the first section is the important bit, ignore the date).

Comment: For me it's `-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 149080`

Comment: Don't read too much into the message from `strace` - that's likely just because `strace` itself is not installed with the setuid bit set - see the `SETUID INSTALLATION` section of `man strace`.

Comment: I still have this problem, but I am pretty certain now that it is related to my WLAN stick, a FRITZ! WLAN AC 860. Even if I up to date used this stick without problems. When unplugged I can use sudo normally, when I try to use it with this stick I get the issue. I am on the kernel 5.4.0-56-generic which as I get should support this stick https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/WLAN/Karten/AVM/